# Problem with the subgroup HK

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to do the next problem

"Let $M,N$ subgroups of the finite group $G$, $MN:=\{mn|m\in M,n\in N\}$. Prove that

$i)$ If $M$ is normal in $G$ then $MN$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $[MN:M]$ is a common divisor of $|N|$ and $[G:M]$.

$ii)$ If $M$ is normal in $G$ and $\gcd(|N|,[G:M]))=1$, then $N\subseteq M$."

I did the first part of $i)$, that $MN$ is a subgroup, it was easy, but the part of de common divisor I can't do it. I tried to use the theorems of isomorphisms but got nothing.

Number $ii)$ I realized that must be easy once I get the part $i)$, 
can you help me?. Thanks!

Comment: from (i) and $\gcd$ condition you get $[MN:M]=1$. So there is only one coset, hence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the second isomorphism theorem, then $MN/M$ is isomorphism to $N/(M\cap N)$, so $[MN:M]$ is equal to $[N:M\cap N]$, which divides $|N|$. For the other one, use $[G:M]=[G:MN][MN:M]$.

For the second part, if $|N|$ and $[G:M]$ are coprime, the common divisor $[MN:M]$ must be $1$, so...

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comments, here's a proof that $K\subseteq L\subseteq G$ implies $[G:K]=[G:L][L:K]$, when $K$ and $L$ are arbitrary subgroups.

For this, let's use the following fact: If $A$ is any subgroup of $G$, then $|G|=[G:A]|A|$. Let's prove this: By definition, $[G:A]$ is the number of distinct left cosets of $A$ in $G$. Let's say $A_1,\ldots,A_{[G:A]}$ are these cosets. Since left cosets partition $G$, and each coset has same cardinality as $A$, we have
$$|G|=\sum_{i=1}^{[G:A]}|A_i|=\sum_{i=1}^{[G:A]}|A|=[G:A]|A|.$$
In particular, we have $[G:A]=|G|/|A|$ ($*$).

Now for the proof of the aforementioned fact: Suppose $K\subseteq L\subseteq G$. Then
$$|K|[G:K]=|G|=|L|[G:L]$$
so $[G:K]=\frac{|L|}{|K|}[G:L]=[L:K][G:L]$ (here we use ($*$) above, with $L$ in place of $G$ and $K$ in place of $A$).

Comment: I understand this but, if I'm not wrong, in order to use $[G:M]=[G:MN][MN:M]$ ,$MN$ need to be normal in $G$ doesn't it?

Comment: @TomBuilder No, this is valid in general: If $K,L$ are subgroups of $G$ with $K\subseteq L\subseteq G$, then $[G:K]=[G:L][L:K]$. I will look up for a reference or write a proof, if I don't find it fast.

Comment: Oh I was thinking that the proof of that fact needs the third isomorphism theorem which needs normality.

Comment: @TomBuilder You are right: This is immediate from the third isomorphism theorem. But, in the finite group case, we can simply count how many left cosets we have for each group. This is also true (with cardinals) in the infinite case, but we need some form of the axiom of choice (pick representatives $l_i$ for the left cosets of $L$ in $G$, and representatives $k_j$ for the left cosets of $K$ in $L$. Then $l_ik_j$ are representatives for the left cosets of $K$ in $G$).

Comment: Thanks! your edited part was very clear. The complete proof is very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You can prove than $|MN|=\dfrac{\vert M \vert \vert N \vert}{\vert M \cap N \vert}$, to get that it divides $\vert N \vert$, for the other part $[G:M]=[G:MN][MN:M]$ (all of the subgroups are contained in one another)